# Maps and margin width

Tags: r, plot, maps

I am creating maps of US states and find that the margin widths are sized to the width of the map itself. In more "narrow" states left and right margin text elements may overlap. 
How can I use the whole width of the window?

I tried all sort of par values but to no avail.

```
map_state <- function(state) {
    map(database = "county", region = state)   
    mtext(side = 1, paste(state, "Map"), adj = 0)
    mtext(side = 1, Sys.Date(), adj = 1)   
}
# ok because NC is "wide"
map_state("North Carolina")
# not ok because IL is "narrow"
map_state("Illinois")
```

[image: NC map]
[image: IL map]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `par("pin")` and the `strwidth` function to determine if the width is narrow, and react accordingly. Try this:

```r
map_state <- function(state) {
    maps::map(database = "county", region = state)   
    lbls <- c(paste(state, "Map"), as.character(Sys.Date()))
    if (sum(strwidth(lbls)) > (0.95*par("pin")[1])) {
      mtext(side = 1, paste(lbls, collapse = "\n"), adj = 0)
    } else {
      mtext(side = 1, lbls, adj = c(0, 1))
    }
}
map_state("North Carolina")
map_state("Illinois")
```

[image: two states]

This method is imperfect, as it assumes a little more empty space in one corner. But it does give one way to detect the near-overlap. I used `0.95*par("pin")[1]` as an arbitary cut-off, so that there is some space between them. Another way to add fixed-width padding could be `sum(strwidth(paste0(lbls, "  ")))`, ymmv.